# How can it be possible to call a java webservice from mysql procedure,where http_get,post() functions are not working?

Tags: mysql

```
IF xyz AND abc THEN
    SELECT http_get(CONCAT ('http://REST_url_from_the_email_provider&NAME=',@firstname,'&MSG=',@message)) 
    INTO @rtn_value; 
END IF;
```

Comment: this is a pipe dream unless you modify the server source code

Comment: This is only a piece of code.What i need is only a function that is analogous to http_post in mysql 5.5

Comment: I don't mean to sound silly but that is not what the server daemon is for. I think you will better understand the core components and boundaries of what things are meant to do, and not do, as you move forward in your programming career or path. Or whatever you are doing.